# How to connect to a high availability SQL Server from Python + SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-server-2012, high-availability

Our infrastructure group has asked us to "add MultiSubnetFailover=True to all application connection strings" so that we can take advantage of a new SQL Server HA setup involving Availability Groups.

I am stuck though since we have some python programs that connect (read+write) to the database via SQL Alchemy. I have been searching and I don't see anything about this MultiSubnetFailover feature being available as an option in SQL Alchemy or any other Python driver. Is it possible to connect to an HA setup utilizing the SQL Alchemy driver, or even Python, and if so how?

FYI - The link that my infrastructure guy pointed me to is here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205662%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and as you can see it is specifically about how .NET applications can utilize the "MultiSubnetFailover=True" setting in the connection string among other things.

Comment: Take a look at [Additional Connection Examples](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mssql.html#additional-connection-examples) of MSSQL dialect. I assume you can just append `?MultiSubnetFailover=True` to the connection string used for `sqlalchemy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#dialect-mssql-pyodbc-connect

You could use the example towards the end of the documentation's section like this:

```
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
connection_string = '127.0.0.1;Database=MyDatabase;MultiSubnetFailover=True'
engine_string = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(urllib.quote_plus(connection_string))
engine = create_engine(engine_string)
```

*Update from comments*

For newer versions of Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server, you may need to use `MultiSubnetFailover=Yes` instead of `True`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nathaniel. I believe where we ended up is that only .NET is currently supporting the MultiSubnetFailover setting. Sure we could pass it through the connection string but it wouldn't actually do anything special (ie, wouldn't successfully have a failover location which is on a different subnet)

Comment: If you're using linux and unixodbc, Microsoft has a driver that supports the MultiSubnetFailover setting. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568455(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the info. We changed our plans and decided not to do it, so I won't be able to test it out, but marking as accepted answer.

Comment: Using the {Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} linked above by @Nathaniel doesn't actually work. It gives: OperationalError: ('08001', "[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid value specified for connection string attribute 'MultiSubnetFailover' (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: You should use MultiSubnetFailover=Yes.. that works