# Connect to a Highly-Available SQL Server from R

Tags: sql-server, r, sql-server-2012, rodbc

We've recently upgraded to SQL Server 2012 which is Highly-Available DR enabled. When connecting using SSMS we need to specify `MultiSubnetFailover=True` additional connection option + increase timeouts.

How can we replicate this in R? Without this, we observe sporadic connectivity/timeout issues.
[Related, but for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158814/how-to-connect-to-a-high-availability-sql-server-from-python-sql-alchemy)

```
> packageVersion('RODBC')
[1] '1.3.6'
> packageVersion('Base')
[1] '2.15.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Data Source Name, you can add extra arguments to `odbcConnect`

```
odbcConnect(DSN, uid = "user_name", pwd = "password", MultiSubnetFailover = "True")
```

If you are using a connection string, you just need to add the arguments in your string.

```
odbcDriverConnect("driver=DRIVER; server=SERVER; database=DATABASE; uid=user_name; pwd=password; MultiSubnetFailover = True")
```